# How to clean HTML from any special tag via Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

How to clean HTML fromany special tag via Regex in C#?

Here is a sample HTML where Ineed to delete `<font size="-2">`

```
R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFYiDC6u3xOGn4JpO-GF83PjdSbtw&amp;url=http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10000872396390444426404577647060576633348.html"><img src="//nt2.ggpht.com/news/tbn/bm6jvTMtF-PpnM/6.jpg" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">Wall Street Journal</font></a></font>
            </td>
```

I know we have to use somehow Regex, but I cannot figure out how we can use it.

I have tried to adjust this method but it cleans ALL tags.

```
public string Strip(string text) 
{ 
   return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty); 
}
```

In fact I am looking to some approach to do like this

```
public string Strip(string text, HTMLTags.Font)
{

}
```

where `HTMLTags.Font` is a enum of some of the HTML tags

```
enum HTMLTags
{
    Font,
    Div,
    Td
    ...
}
```

Thank you for any clue!!!

Comment: Standard answer: Don't use RegEx for HTML, use SgmlReader or HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: A real easy (and inflexible) way to do that would be to put the tagname after the first `<` in your regex.

Comment: @Matthew But what if the tag looks like FONT Font font ?

Comment: I second the Agility pack here.

Comment: @Terminador The case-insensitivity mode can be toggled for regular expressions. However, it still has the problem of being a regular expression :)

Comment: @Terminador `RegExOptions.IgnoreCase`.

Comment: Use a case insensitive regex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var font in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("font").ToArray())
{
    font.Remove();
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how we can get cleaned html from doc object, please?

Comment: @Terminador `doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`

Comment: Sorry but it reterns HTML only without any plain text. So the text is lost somehow... It is  odd...

Comment: I mean It font.Remove();  removes node but I have to keep the text there.

Comment: @Terminador Above code is just an example and you may need to read some docs about HtmlAgilityPack. Try this `font.ParentNode.RemoveChild(font, true);`

Answer (score 2):

The best for this should be [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It's not a regex but the parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML.

Answer (score 1):

While [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is, most probably, the best option *(as it allows you to perform LINQ queries and/or XPath queries against a DOM like representation of the HTML)*. A start could be the following:

```
public static class HTMLTags
{
    public string Font { get { return "<font>" } }
    public string Div { get { return "<div>" } }
    public string Td { get { return "<td>" } }
}
```

then, in your client code:

```
public string Strip(string text, HTMLTags.Font)
{
    /* string parse/replace occurances of HTMLTags.Font  */
}
```